# How to preprocess my ImageDataset using Keras (Augmentation, Split)

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, google-colaboratory

I have a project on object detection.
I have few data and want to apply the data augmentation method using Keras, but I am taking errors when I try to split and save my data into training and test.

How can I do all of this?

what I want to do?

First, I want to resize my image dataset then split data randomly into training and test.
After that saving into 'training' 'test' directory then I want to implement data augmentation for the training folder.

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.xception import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
 data_dir=/..path/
ds_gen = ImageDataGenerator(
preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
validation_split=0.2 
)

train_ds = ds_gen.flow_from_directory(
"data_dir", 
seed=1,
target_size=(150, 150), #adjust to your needs
batch_size=32,#adjust to your needs
save_to_dir= data_dir/training
subset='training' 
 )

val_ds = ds_gen.flow_from_directory(
"data_dir",
seed=1,
target_size=(150, 150),
batch_size=32,
save_to_dir= data_dir/validation
subset='validation'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_dataframe to do what you wish. Since you are using flow from directory your data is organized so that the code below will read in the image information and create a train_df, a test_df and a valid_df set of data frames:

```
def preprocess (sdir, trsplit, vsplit, random_seed):
    filepaths=[]
    labels=[]    
    classlist=os.listdir(sdir)
    for klass in classlist:
        classpath=os.path.join(sdir,klass)
        flist=os.listdir(classpath)
        for f in flist:
            fpath=os.path.join(classpath,f)
            filepaths.append(fpath)
            labels.append(klass)
    Fseries=pd.Series(filepaths, name='filepaths')
    Lseries=pd.Series(labels, name='labels')
    df=pd.concat([Fseries, Lseries], axis=1)       
    # split df into train_df and test_df 
    dsplit=vsplit/(1-trsplit)
    strat=df['labels']    
    train_df, dummy_df=train_test_split(df, train_size=trsplit, shuffle=True, random_state=random_seed, stratify=strat)
    strat=dummy_df['labels']
    valid_df, test_df=train_test_split(dummy_df, train_size=dsplit, shuffle=True, random_state=random_seed, stratify=strat)
    print('train_df length: ', len(train_df), '  test_df length: ',len(test_df), '  valid_df length: ', len(valid_df))
    print(train_df['labels'].value_counts())
    return train_df, test_df, valid_df
    
sdir=/..path/
train_split=.8 # set this to the % of data you want for the train set
valid_split=.1 # set this to the % of the data you want for a validation set
# note % used for test is 1-train_split-valid_split
train_df, test_df, valid_df= preprocess(sdir,train_split, valid_split)
```

The function will show the balance between the classes in terms of how many sample there are in the training dataframe for each class. Examine this data and decide how on the number of samples you want in every class. For example is class0 has 3000 samples, class1 has 1200 samples and class2 has 800 samples you may decide that for the training dataframe you want to have every class have 1000 samples (max_samples=1000). That implies that for class 2 you have to create 200 augmented images, and for classes 0 and 1 you need to reduce the number of images. The functions below will do that for you.
The trim function trims the maximum number of samples in a class. The balance function use the trim function, then creates directories to store the augmented images, creates an aug_df dataframe and merges it with the train_df data frame. The result is a composite dataframe ndf that serves as the composite training set and is balanced with exactly max_samples of samples in each class.

```
def trim (df, max_size, min_size, column):
    df=df.copy()
    sample_list=[] 
    groups=df.groupby(column)
    for label in df[column].unique():        
        group=groups.get_group(label)
        sample_count=len(group)         
        if sample_count> max_size :
            samples=group.sample(max_size, replace=False, weights=None, random_state=123, axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
            sample_list.append(samples)
        elif sample_count>= min_size:
            sample_list.append(group)
    df=pd.concat(sample_list, axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
    balance=list(df[column].value_counts())
    print (balance)
    return df
def balance(train_df,max_samples, min_samples, column, working_dir, image_size):
    train_df=train_df.copy()
    train_df=trim (train_df, max_samples, min_samples, column)    
    # make directories to store augmented images
    aug_dir=os.path.join(working_dir, 'aug')
    if os.path.isdir(aug_dir):
        shutil.rmtree(aug_dir)
    os.mkdir(aug_dir)
    for label in train_df['labels'].unique():    
        dir_path=os.path.join(aug_dir,label)    
        os.mkdir(dir_path)
    # create and store the augmented images  
    total=0
    gen=ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True,  rotation_range=20, width_shift_range=.2,
                                  height_shift_range=.2, zoom_range=.2)
    groups=train_df.groupby('labels') # group by class
    for label in train_df['labels'].unique():  # for every class               
        group=groups.get_group(label)  # a dataframe holding only rows with the specified label 
        sample_count=len(group)   # determine how many samples there are in this class  
        if sample_count< max_samples: # if the class has less than target number of images
            aug_img_count=0
            delta=max_samples-sample_count  # number of augmented images to create
            target_dir=os.path.join(aug_dir, label)  # define where to write the images    
            aug_gen=gen.flow_from_dataframe( group,  x_col='filepaths', y_col=None, target_size=image_size,
                                            class_mode=None, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, 
                                            save_to_dir=target_dir, save_prefix='aug-', color_mode='rgb',
                                            save_format='jpg')
            while aug_img_count<delta:
                images=next(aug_gen)            
                aug_img_count += len(images)
            total +=aug_img_count
    print('Total Augmented images created= ', total)
    # create aug_df and merge with train_df to create composite training set ndf
    if total>0:
        aug_fpaths=[]
        aug_labels=[]
        classlist=os.listdir(aug_dir)
        for klass in classlist:
            classpath=os.path.join(aug_dir, klass)     
            flist=os.listdir(classpath)    
            for f in flist:        
                fpath=os.path.join(classpath,f)         
                aug_fpaths.append(fpath)
                aug_labels.append(klass)
        Fseries=pd.Series(aug_fpaths, name='filepaths')
        Lseries=pd.Series(aug_labels, name='labels')
        aug_df=pd.concat([Fseries, Lseries], axis=1)
        ndf=pd.concat([train_df,aug_df], axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
    else:
        ndf=train_df
    print (list(ndf['labels'].value_counts()) )
    return ndf 

    
max_samples= 1000 # set this to how many samples you want in each class
min_samples=0
column='labels'
working_dir = r'./' # this is the directory where the augmented images will be stored
img_size=(224,224) # set this to the image size you want for the images
ndf=balance(train_df,max_samples, min_samples, column, working_dir, img_size)
```

now create the train, test and valid generators

```
channels=3
batch_size=30
img_shape=(img_size[0], img_size[1], channels)
length=len(test_df)
test_batch_size=sorted([int(length/n) for n in range(1,length+1) if length % n ==0 and length/n<=80],reverse=True)[0]  
test_steps=int(length/test_batch_size)
print ( 'test batch size: ' ,test_batch_size, '  test steps: ', test_steps)
def scalar(img):    
    return img  # EfficientNet expects pixelsin range 0 to 255 so no scaling is required
trgen=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=scalar, horizontal_flip=True)
tvgen=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=scalar)
train_gen=trgen.flow_from_dataframe( ndf, x_col='filepaths', y_col='labels', target_size=img_size, class_mode='categorical',
                                    color_mode='rgb', shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size)
test_gen=tvgen.flow_from_dataframe( test_df, x_col='filepaths', y_col='labels', target_size=img_size, class_mode='categorical',
                                    color_mode='rgb', shuffle=False, batch_size=test_batch_size)

valid_gen=tvgen.flow_from_dataframe( valid_df, x_col='filepaths', y_col='labels', target_size=img_size, class_mode='categorical',
                                    color_mode='rgb', shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size)
classes=list(train_gen.class_indices.keys())
class_count=len(classes)
```

now use the train_gen and valid_gen in model.fit. Use the test_gen in model.evaluate or model.predict